# restrict cin. operator to a specific range

Tags: c++

what if i wanted to limit the range of cin operator? something like the code below, where i take the input from the user, now the input must be less than 100 i.e. if the user enters marks > 100 it should report an error message.

```
using namespace std;

void GetInput(const std::string &prompt, int &i, int max)
{
    bool valid = false;
 do
  {
    cout << prompt;
    if (cin >> i && i < max)
    {
        valid = true;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Error: Input must be less than " << max << "." << endl;
    }
} while (!valid);
```

}

```
class Marks
{
private:
int elec, prog, math, perc = NULL; 

public:

void input()
{

        cout << "enter the marks obtained in Mathematics = ";
        cin >> math;
        cout << "enter the marks obtained in Programming = ";
        cin >> prog;
        cout << "enter the marks obtained in Electronics = ";
        cin >>elec;


} 

void avg()
{
    double avg = NULL;
    avg = (math + prog + elec) / 3;
    cout << "Average = " << avg << endl;
}


void Perc()
{

    perc = ((math + elec + prog)*100) / 300;
    cout << "The Percentage = " << perc <<" %"<< endl;

}


 void grade()
{

     if (perc >= 79)
     {
         cout << "A" << endl;
     }
     else if ((perc > 66) && (perc < 80))
         cout << "B" << endl;

    else if (perc < 66)
        cout << "C" << endl;
}

};

int main(void)
{
    Marks m;
    int maths, prog, elec;
    GetInput("enter the marks obtained in Mathematics = ", maths, 100);
    GetInput("enter the marks obtained in Programming = ", prog, 100);
    GetInput("enter the marks obtained in Electronics = ", elec, 100);

    m.Perc();
    m.avg();
    m.grade();
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: A typical solution for an exercise like this is simply to check the value and iterate until the input is within the range expected.

Comment: i get the idea of it, any example would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
int maths;
bool valid = false;
do
{
    cout << "Enter the marks obtained in Mathematics = ";
    if (cin >> maths && maths < 100)
    {
        valid = true;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Error: Input must be less than 100." << endl;
    }
} while (!valid);
```

This will ensure that the input is both a valid integer value and less than 100, only terminating the loop once valid input has been entered.

To do it generically:

```
void GetInput(const std::string &prompt, int &i, int max)
{
  bool valid = false;
  do
  {
      cout << prompt;
      if (cin >> i && i < max)
      {
          valid = true;
      }
      else
      {
          cout << "Error: Input must be less than " << max << "." << endl;
      }
  } while (!valid);
}
```

And to call it in your code:

```
int maths, prog, elec;
GetInput("enter the marks obtained in Mathematics = ", maths, 100);
GetInput("enter the marks obtained in Programming = ", prog, 100);
GetInput("enter the marks obtained in Electronics = ", elec, 100);
```

Comment: with that approach, i would have to write the bunch of codes for every subject. the typeOfData is validated already i just need to restrict the user to enter the marks below 100.

Comment: You'd need to move it in to a function. I've edited my original answer with an example of how to do that.

Comment: +1 for using the concept of using another function.
but still, isn't there any way to simply apply the Range-Check in the function already?

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no way directly built in to std::cin.

Comment: Did you #include <string>? It works in Visual Studio 2012. If it still isn't working, post the error, and I'll take a look.

Comment: GetInput: identifier not found. #VS13

Comment: Did you copy and paste the function at the top of your file (after the #includes but before void input())? The compiler is telling you that it doesn't know what "GetInput" is, which implies it does not have access to the function's declaration.

Comment: it works like magic. but there is a problem and that is, when it goes to another function from main named cal_perc(); it does not take the user inputted values now and shows 0 %. same happens when it goes to other functions like cal_avg(); or calc_grade(); what am i forgetting?

Comment: You will need to call GetInput in cal_perc (the same way as in input) if it needs to take user input.

Comment: it does not take input simply calculates the percentage depending on the user inputted values earlier in the Input(); should i paste the code? im sorry for driving you nuts :/

Comment: Paste the code on pastebin and I can take a look. My guess is that your variables have gone out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, a bit of operator overloading can hide the complexity in a reusable helper class:

```
template<typename TMin, typename TMax>
struct unbound_limit_range
{
    const TMin lower_limit;
    const TMax upper_limit;
};

template<typename TMin, typename TMax>
class bound_limit_range
{
    std::istream& the_stream;
    const unbound_limit_range<TMin, TMax> the_limits;
public:
    bound_limit_range(istream& p_stream, const unbound_limit_range<TMin, TMax>& p_limits)
         : the_stream(p_stream), the_limits(p_limits)
    {}

    template<typename TVar>
    istream& operator>>(T& dest)
    {
        while (true) {
            if (!(the_stream >> dest)) return the_stream;

            if (dest < the_limits.lower_limit) {
                std::cout << "Value too low\n";
            }
            else if (dest > the_limits.upper_limit) {
                std::cout << "Value too high\n";
            }
            else {
                return the_stream;
            }

            std::cout << "Try again: " << std::flush;
        }
    }
};

template<typename TMin, typename TMax>
bound_limit_range<TMin, TMax> operator>>(std::istream& stream, const limit_range<TMin, TMax>& limits) { return { stream, limits }; }

template<typename TMin, typename TMax>
unbound_limit_range<TMin, TMax> limit_range(TMin lower, TMax upper) { return { lower, upper }; }
```

Quite a mess, but then you can simply write:

```
cout << "enter the marks obtained in Mathematics = ";
cin >> limit_range(0, 100) >> maths;
cout << "enter the marks obtained in Programming = ";
cin >> limit_range(0, 100) >> prog;
cout << "enter the marks obtained in Electronics = ";
cin >> limit_range(0, 100) >> elec;

if (cin) { /* all succeeded */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a manipulator that does this for you:

```c++
#include <iostream>

template<int, int>
struct input_range_impl
{
    input_range_impl(int& val) : val_(val)
    {
    }

    template<int I, int U>
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, const input_range_impl<I, U>&);
private:
    int& val_;
};

template<int I, int U>
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, const input_range_impl<I, U>& manip)
{
    if (!(is >> manip.val_) || !(I <= manip.val_ && manip.val_ >= U))
        is.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
    return is;
}

template<int I, int U>
input_range_impl<I, U> input_range(int& val)
{
    return { val };
}

void input()
{
    std::cout << "enter the marks obtained in Mathematics = ";
    std::cin >> input_range<0, 100>(maths);
    std::cout << "enter the marks obtained in Programming = ";
    std::cin >> input_range<0, 100>(prog);
    std::cout << "enter the marks obtained in Electronics = ";
    std::cin >> input_range<0, 100>(elec);
}
```

Comment: the idea of creating a manipulator is even more fascinating :D but knowing the fact that I'm still learning sucks. -_-
do you mind explaining a bit about the templates in structs AAANNDD i copied pasted, it gives garbage value :/

Comment: @MuneerKhan Change `<= U` to `>= U`, that should fix it. But the basic idea is that the the function `input_range` returns a class `input_range_impl` that overloads the extractor so that it can do range checking. If the value extracted is not within the range, we set an error in the streams error mask.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to my other answer, here's another way to set a range but incorporate the semantics into `std::num_get<facet>` installed in the stream's locale. It's a bit more complicated, but it overrides the stream's default behavior for extracting integers and uses the custom range checking code:

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

int input_range() { static int idx = std::ios_base::xalloc(); return idx; }

void erase_range(std::ios_base::event evt, std::ios_base& str, int index)
{
    if (evt == std::ios_base::erase_event)
    {
        delete static_cast<std::pair<int, int>*>(str.pword(index));
    }
}

class num_get : public std::num_get<char>
{
public:
    iter_type do_get( iter_type in, iter_type end, std::ios_base& str, 
                      std::ios_base::iostate& err, long& v ) const
    {
        long temp;
        in = std::num_get<char>::do_get(in, end, str, err, temp);

        if (in != end)
            err |= std::ios_base::failbit;

        void*& p = str.pword(input_range());

        if (p)
        {
            auto values = *static_cast<std::pair<int, int>*>(p);
            if (!(values.first <= temp && temp <= values.second))
            {
                err |= std::ios_base::failbit;
            } else
                v = temp;
        }
        return in;
    }
};

template<int I, int J>
std::istream& set_range(std::istream& is)
{
    void*& p = is.pword(input_range());
    erase_range(std::ios_base::erase_event, is, input_range());

    if (is)
    {
        p = new std::pair<int, int>(I, J);

        if (!dynamic_cast<const num_get*>(
                &std::use_facet<std::num_get<char>>(is.getloc())))
        {
            is.imbue(std::locale(is.getloc(), new num_get));
            is.register_callback(&erase_range, input_range());
        }
    }
    return is;
}
```

You can use it like this:

```c++
void input()
{
    std::cin >> set_range<0, 100>;

    std::cout << "enter the marks obtained in Mathematics = ";
    if (!(std::cin >> maths))
        std::cout << "Error!";
    std::cout << "enter the marks obtained in Programming = ";
    // so on...
    std::cout << "enter the marks obtained in Electronics = ";
    // and so forth...
}
```