# Limiting the inputs and again asking the user for the right range

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm stuck on this program: I have to limit the input but the program just totally ignore the if statement if i enter a value greater or equal to 100 it should 
display an error but continue to ask user for input and run

Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a[4][4], big1, n, m, i, j, loc1, loc2;
    cout << "Enter no of rows and columns:";
    cin >> m >> n;
    cout << "Enter the array:\n";

    if (n > 100 || m>100 )
    {
        cout << "Error! number should in range of (1 to 99)." << endl;
        cout << "Enter the number again: ";
        cin >> m >> n;
    }
    else 
        for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < n; ++j)
            {
                cin >> a[i][j];
            }
        }

cout << endl << "Entered Matrix: " << endl;

for (i = 0; i < m; ++i)
    for (j = 0; j < n; ++j)
    {
        cout << " " << a[i][j];
        if (j == n - 1)
            cout << endl << endl;
    }


big1 = a[0][0];
loc1 = 0;
loc2 = 0;
for (i = 0; i < m; ++i)
{
    for (j = 0; j<n; ++j)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i<4; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j<4; j++)
                if (a[i][j]>big1)
                {
                    big1 = a[i][j];
                    loc1 = i;
                    loc2 = j;
                }
    }
}

cout << "\nLargest number:" << big1 << endl;
cout << "The position that had the largest number is in " << " Row " << loc1 << " " << "Column " << loc2 << endl;
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [restrict cin. operator to a specific range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23524846/restrict-cin-operator-to-a-specific-range)

Comment: If you want to reject equal to 100 as well, you should include it in your comparison: `n >= 100` - on the other hand, what happens if user enters bad input *again*? Replace `if` with `while` and this would be covered. You do not check stream states after input. What, if user input was entirely invalid (e. g. `vw7`)? Next time stream reads [bad values](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) (since c++11, before, did not modify variables).

Answer (score 0):

I've added a while to repeat the check until the number falls below 100. Please note the line "int a[4][4],.." will overrun if you exceed 4 rows * 4 columns. I suggest moving its initialization to a lower position when rows and columns are known.

Try this :

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int big1, n, m, i, j, loc1, loc2;
cout << "Enter no of rows and columns:";
cin >> m >> n;
cout << "Enter the array:\n";

while (n > 100 || m>100 )
   {
      cout << "Error! number should in range of (1 to 99)." << endl;
      cout << "Enter the number again: ";
      cin >> m >> n;

   }
int a[m][n];
//else  redundant
for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < n; ++j)
    {
        cin >> a[i][j];
    }
}
cout << endl << "Entered Matrix: " << endl;
for (i = 0; i < m; ++i)
    for (j = 0; j < n; ++j)
    {
        cout << " " << a[i][j];
        if (j == n - 1)
            cout << endl << endl;
    }


big1 = a[0][0];
loc1 = 0;
loc2 = 0;
for (i = 0; i < m; ++i)
{
    for (j = 0; j<n; ++j)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i<4; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j<4; j++)
                if (a[i][j]>big1)
                {
                    big1 = a[i][j];
                    loc1 = i;
                    loc2 = j;
                }
    }
}

cout << "\nLargest number:" << big1 << endl;
cout << "The position that had the largest number is in " << " Row " << loc1 << " " << "Column " << loc2 << endl;
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```